# Using hierarchical blocks in redhawk

Tags: redhawksdr

Is there a way to use hirarchical blocks in redhawk? 
For example, say I want to make a digital modulator that is a composition of filters, upsamplers, etc, and I want to use it as a single block in a waveform project, that has other hierarchical components as well. How would I combine the already made filter and upsampler blocks into the digital modulator block using redhawk?

Answer (score 0):

You currently cannot create waveforms of waveforms. A waveform can however have external ports, and external properties allowing you to chain waveforms together dynamically and treat it similar to a component from a programmatic perspective. For example in the example below I launch two waveforms on the domain and connect the two, these waveforms are the examples that come bundled with REDHAWK and have external ports and properties.

```
>>> from ossie.utils import redhawk
>>> dom = redhawk.attach()
>>> wf1 = dom.createApplication('/waveforms/rh/FM_mono_demo/FM_mono_demo.sad.xml')
>>> wf2 = dom.createApplication('/waveforms/rh/FM_mono_demo/FM_mono_demo.sad.xml')
>>> wf1.connect(wf2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a construct for a component of components (other than a waveform).  As of the REDHAWK 2.1 beta release there **is** a 'shared address' construct that allows you to do something similar to what you seem to be asking for.  The 'shared address' BULKIO pattern was specifically developed to create high-speed connections between components and reduce the processing load caused by IO.  Take a look at https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/core-framework/tree/develop-2.1/docs/shared-address and see if this is what you are looking for.  It will allow you to launch 'N' components built according to the shared address pattern into a single *component host* and still retain each individual components property interfaces etc.

If you are more specific about *why* you want to use a hierarchical block, a more targeted answer may be possible.